# Fix Exercise Type in Activity App

Tags: ios, activity.app

I did 60m of yoga yesterday and didn’t realize until the end that I had accidentally specified Indoor Cycle as the activity type.  Looking for a place to edit this in the Activity app on my phone and can’t seem to locate this option.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Today tab in the Activity tab and swipe to get to *yesterday*. You should see the activity and its duration in a big box. Tap it, and scroll to find *Show all Data*. You can delete the particular entry there.

Adding is similar, go to some day you did yoga on, Tap on the said big box and find red + at the top right.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not at all following this.  What I want to do is *edit*, not add or delete.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @AJ. You can take a screenshot for all the details like time began, time end etc., under Cycling and fill the same in the Yoga. I don't know of editing it.